# boost::lockfree::spsc_queue - segmentation fault after some seconds

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, buffer, lock-free

- Using `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue` with `uint_16` data
- Quick explanation of program: From within a thread `uint_16` data is continuously delivered by an acquisition object and pushed to the `spsc_queue` (producer). Meanwhile in the parent process "one second" length data is popped from the `spsc_queue` when avaliable (consumer).
- Getting segmentation faults, but have not been able to find the root cause so far.
- Have been using `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue` with data type `int` in several project so far without any issues.

**Complete source:**

```
#include <Acquisition.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>

size_t sample_rate_Hz = 250e3;

void data_acqui(boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<uint16_t>& bf, std::atomic<bool>& stop)
{
    try
    {
        uint16_t *data;
        uint32_t data_size = 0;

        // acquisition channels 1-4
        std::vector<Channel> channels;
        channels.emplace_back(Channel::ANALOG, Channel::ATT_15dB, false);
        channels.emplace_back(Channel::ANALOG, Channel::ATT_15dB, false);
        channels.emplace_back(Channel::ANALOG, Channel::ATT_15dB, false);
        channels.emplace_back(Channel::ANALOG, Channel::ATT_15dB, false);

        Acquisition Acq(channels, sample_rate_Hz, 0);

        while(!stop.load())
        {
            data = Acq.get(&data_size);

            if(data_size && data != NULL)
            {
                // data_size is number of bytes delivered by Acquisition::get class method
                // adapt size to data type used by spsc_queue
                data_size /= sizeof(*data);

                std::cout << "THREAD: bf.push(data, data_size) => data:" << data << " data_size:" << data_size << std::endl;

                bf.push(data, data_size);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "MAIN: sample_rate_Hz: " << std::dec << sample_rate_Hz << std::endl;
        // 4 channels data acquisition
        size_t oneSecChunkSize = 4 * sample_rate_Hz;
        std::cout << "MAIN: oneSecChunkSize: " << std::dec << oneSecChunkSize << std::endl;


        // 5 sec buffer
        boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<uint16_t> sec_buffer(5 * oneSecChunkSize);


        std::atomic<bool> stop(false);
        std::thread th(data_acqui,std::ref(sec_buffer), std::ref(stop));


        // helper used to empty spsc_queue when data of a single second length is available
        std::vector<uint16_t> oneSecChunk(oneSecChunkSize ,0);


        // let's record 10 seconds
        size_t num_sec = 10;

        for(size_t i = 0; i < num_sec; ++i)
        {
            while(sec_buffer.read_available() <= oneSecChunkSize)
            {
                std::cout <<  "MAIN: waiting..." << std::dec << sec_buffer.read_available() << " <= " << oneSecChunkSize << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            }

            std::cout << "MAIN: number of seconds recorded:  " << (i+1) << "/" << num_sec << " sec" << std::endl;
            sec_buffer.pop(oneSecChunk.data(), oneSecChunkSize);
        }

        std::cout << "stop thread..." << std::endl;
        stop = true;
        std::cout << "join thread..." << std::endl;
        th.join();

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**GDB:**

```
user@linux:~ gdb -ex run ./main
Reading symbols from ./main...done.
Starting program: /root/main 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
MAIN: sample_rate_Hz: 250000
MAIN: oneSecChunkSize: 1000000
[New Thread 0xb638d450 (LWP 29640)]
MAIN: waiting...0 <= 1000000
MAIN: waiting...0 <= 1000000
MAIN: waiting...0 <= 1000000
THREAD: bf.push(data, data_size) => data:0xb5400000 data_size:172032
MAIN: waiting...172032 <= 1000000
MAIN: waiting...172032 <= 1000000
THREAD: bf.push(data, data_size) => data:0xb54a8000 data_size:172032
MAIN: waiting...344064 <= 1000000
MAIN: waiting...344064 <= 1000000
THREAD: bf.push(data, data_size) => data:0xb5550000 data_size:172032
MAIN: waiting...516096 <= 1000000
MAIN: waiting...516096 <= 1000000
MAIN: waiting...516096 <= 1000000
THREAD: bf.push(data, data_size) => data:0xb55f8000 data_size:172032
MAIN: waiting...688128 <= 1000000
MAIN: waiting...688128 <= 1000000
THREAD: bf.push(data, data_size) => data:0xb56a0000 data_size:172032
MAIN: waiting...860160 <= 1000000
MAIN: waiting...860160 <= 1000000
THREAD: bf.push(data, data_size) => data:0xb5748000 data_size:172032
MAIN: number of seconds recorded:  1/10 sec
MAIN: waiting...32192 <= 1000000
MAIN: waiting...32192 <= 1000000
THREAD: bf.push(data, data_size) => data:0xb57f0000 data_size:172032
MAIN: waiting...32192 <= 1000000

Thread 2 "main" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb638d450 (LWP 29640)]
0xb6dec564 in __memcpy_neon () at ../sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch/memcpy_impl.S:591
591 ../sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch/memcpy_impl.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6dec564 in __memcpy_neon () at ../sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch/memcpy_impl.S:591
#1  0x0002e162 in std::__copy_move<false, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m<unsigned short> (__first=0xb57f0000, __last=0xb5844000, 
    __result=0xb6586008) at /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:378
#2  0x0002e28e in std::__copy_move_a<false, unsigned short const*, unsigned short*> (__first=0xb57f0000, __last=0xb5844000, __result=0xb6586008)
    at /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:396
#3  0x0002e12e in std::__copy_move_a2<false, unsigned short const*, unsigned short*> (__first=0xb57f0000, __last=0xb5844000, __result=0xb6586008)
    at /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:434
#4  0x0002df36 in std::copy<unsigned short const*, unsigned short*> (__first=0xb57f0000, __last=0xb5844000, __result=0xb6586008)
    at /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/stl_algobase.h:466
#5  0x0002dd66 in std::__uninitialized_copy<true>::__uninit_copy<unsigned short const*, unsigned short*> (__first=0xb57f0000, __last=0xb5844000, 
    __result=0xb6586008) at /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:93
#6  0x0002dbb2 in std::uninitialized_copy<unsigned short const*, unsigned short*> (__first=0xb57f0000, __last=0xb5844000, __result=0xb6586008)
    at /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:126
#7  0x0002d914 in boost::lockfree::detail::ringbuffer_base<unsigned short>::push<unsigned short const*> (this=0xbefffa80, begin=0xb57f0000, 
    end=0xb5844000, internal_buffer=0xb638e008, max_size=5000001)
    at /home/user/repo/platform/sysroot/usr/include/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp:149
#8  0x0002d24c in boost::lockfree::detail::ringbuffer_base<unsigned short>::push (this=0xbefffa80, input_buffer=0xb57f0000, input_count=172032, 
    internal_buffer=0xb638e008, max_size=5000001) at /home/user/repo/platform/sysroot/usr/include/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp:118
#9  0x0002c9ba in boost::lockfree::detail::runtime_sized_ringbuffer<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> >::push (this=0xbefffa80, 
    t=0xb57f0000, size=172032) at /home/user/repo/platform/sysroot/usr/include/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp:592
#10 0x0002c0ac in boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<unsigned short, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>::push (this=0xbefffa80, t=0xb57f0000, 
    size=172032) at /home/user/repo/platform/sysroot/usr/include/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp:803
#11 0x0002b7d6 in data_acqui (bf=..., stop=...) at main.cpp:37
#12 0x0002e9b4 in std::_Bind_simple<void (*(std::reference_wrapper<boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<unsigned short, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_> >, std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic<bool> >))(boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<unsigned short, boost::parameter::void_, boost::parameter::void_>&, std::atomic<bool>&)>::_M_invoke<0u, 1u>(std::_Index_tuple<0u, 1u>) (this=0x5d330) at /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9.3/functional:1700
```

**GDB - stackframe 7:**

```
(gdb) frame 7
#7  0x0040ab98 in boost::lockfree::detail::ringbuffer_base<unsigned short>::push<unsigned short const*> (this=0xbefffa78, begin=0xb57f0000, 
    end=0xb5844000, internal_buffer=0xb638e008, max_size=5000001)
    at /home/marx/repos/alpha-buildenv/platform-ia/sysroot/usr/include/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp:149
149             std::uninitialized_copy(begin, last, internal_buffer + write_index);
(gdb) 
#7  0x0040ab98 in boost::lockfree::detail::ringbuffer_base<unsigned short>::push<unsigned short const*> (this=0xbefffa78, begin=0xb57f0000, 
    end=0xb5844000, internal_buffer=0xb638e008, max_size=5000001)
    at /home/marx/repos/alpha-buildenv/platform-ia/sysroot/usr/include/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp:149
149             std::uninitialized_copy(begin, last, internal_buffer + write_index);
(gdb) info locals
write_index = 1032192
read_index = 1000000
avail = 4967808
input_count = 172032
new_write_index = 1204224
last = 0xb5844000
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `Acquisition` as well?

Comment: @MikevanDyke I don't mean to be rude, but is it relevant (long proprietary codebase)? Would gdb not point to the acquisition code if it would be the root cause? It does point to the spsc queue though. 

Furthermore the Acquisition delivers a pointer to data. What would happen if some of the data is pointing to some not allowed memory? Would the spsc queue react as it does right now? Thx

Comment: Yes and no. If Acquisition produces undefined behaviour it might cause the seg fault in `bf.push`. It's unlikely but possible. Also it is hard to reproduce and check for the error. But I understand, that you don't want to provide the code as it's proprietary. We'll have to find another way. I guess in `Acquisition` you read from hardware, so trying another platform is not possible? But have you tried another compiler?

Comment: Or you could switch to stackframe 7 and check if the [`write_index`](https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree/blob/develop/include/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp#L130) points to a valid location inside the ring_buffer

Comment: I sadly cannot disclose the source code and/or change the platform. I used gcc-8, but still same error. Strangly enough by using isolation, meaning only getting data from acquisition or only pushing self created data to the spsc queue, the program doesn't crash. So the combination of both is the problem.

Comment: I will check for the stackframe 7 and publish the results in the question above.

Comment: I'm getting closer to the issue. Now I'm certain it comes from the proprietary Acquisition codebase. What I did, was just walking the pointer delivered by the `Acquisition::get` member and dereferencing it, until the segmentation fault appeared. @MikevanDyke Thanks for your support.